# llvm ir optimisation "Use still stuck around after Def is destroyed" error function deletion

Tags: compilation, llvm, compiler-optimization, jit, llvm-ir

Hi I recently upgraded to llvm 4.0 and now I am getting the strangest errors from the optimiser at what seems to be the most benign code. I have identified the code that seems to give me the error below, and the print out of the assertion that llvm gives me pertaining to a `<badref>` however no `<badref>` is visible in the code it is talking about. This makes me think that it could be a compiler error or the generated code is incorrect.

```
; ModuleID = '__form__module.$static.196'
source_filename = "__form__module.$static.196"
target datalayout = "e-m:w-i64:64-f80:128-n8:16:32:64-S128"

%struct.clousure_type = type { void ()*, %struct.closure_vtable*, i8* }
%struct.closure_vtable = type { %struct.type_info*, void (i8*, i8*)*, void (i8*)*, i8 (i8*, i8*)*, i64 (i8*, i8*)* }
%struct.type_info = type { i8*, i8*, i64, i8, i8, i8, i8, %struct.type_info**, %struct.member_info* }
%struct.member_info = type { i8, %struct.type_info* }

@"$static.159$stub_ptr" = external hidden externally_initialized global void (%struct.clousure_type*, %struct.clousure_type*)*

define hidden void @"$static.196"(%struct.clousure_type*, %struct.clousure_type*, %struct.clousure_type*, i8) {
entry:
  %4 = icmp eq i8 %3, 0
  br i1 %4, label %bb2, label %bb4

bb2:                                              ; preds = %entry
  %5 = icmp eq %struct.clousure_type* %0, %2
  br i1 %5, label %bb3, label %bb6

bb3:                                              ; preds = %bb4, %bb2
  ret void

bb4:                                              ; preds = %entry
  %6 = icmp eq %struct.clousure_type* %1, %2
  br i1 %6, label %bb3, label %bb6

bb6:                                              ; preds = %bb4, %bb2
  tail call void @"$static.159"(%struct.clousure_type* %0, %struct.clousure_type* %1)
  ret void
}

; Function Attrs: alwaysinline
define available_externally hidden void @"$static.159"(%struct.clousure_type*, %struct.clousure_type*) #0 {
entry:
  %2 = load void (%struct.clousure_type*, %struct.clousure_type*)*, void (%struct.clousure_type*, %struct.clousure_type*)** @"$static.159$stub_ptr", align 8
  tail call void %2(%struct.clousure_type* %0, %struct.clousure_type* %1)
  ret void
}

attributes #0 = { alwaysinline }


While deleting: void (%struct.clousure_type*, %struct.clousure_type*)* %$static.159
Use still stuck around after Def is destroyed:  call void @"$static.159"(%struct.clousure_type* <badref>, %struct.clousure_type* %0)

This application has requested the Runtime to terminate it in an unusual way.
Please contact the application's support team for more information.
Assertion failed!

Program: C:\Users\RICH\workspace\formvm\Debug\formvm.exe
File: C:\llvm-4.0.0.src\lib\IR\Value.cpp, Line 85

Expression: use_empty() && "Uses remain when a value is destroyed!"
```

The llvm ir code that the optimizer is working on, that represent the above 2 functions, are the following 2 functions (generated from c++).

```
define private void @gen__fun__return_copy85(%struct.clousure_type*, %struct.clousure_type*, %struct.clousure_type*, i8) {
entry:
  %4 = alloca %struct.clousure_type*, align 8
  store %struct.clousure_type* %0, %struct.clousure_type** %4, align 8
  %5 = load %struct.clousure_type*, %struct.clousure_type** %4, align 8
  %6 = alloca %struct.clousure_type*, align 8
  store %struct.clousure_type* %1, %struct.clousure_type** %6, align 8
  %7 = load %struct.clousure_type*, %struct.clousure_type** %6, align 8
  %8 = alloca %struct.clousure_type*, align 8
  store %struct.clousure_type* %2, %struct.clousure_type** %8, align 8
  %9 = load %struct.clousure_type*, %struct.clousure_type** %8, align 8
  %10 = alloca i8, align 8
  store i8 %3, i8* %10, align 8
  %11 = load i8, i8* %10, align 8
  %12 = icmp eq i8 %11, 0
  br i1 %12, label %bb2, label %bb4

bb2:                                              ; preds = %entry
  %13 = icmp eq %struct.clousure_type* %5, %9
  br i1 %13, label %bb3, label %bb6

bb3:                                              ; preds = %bb2
  ret void

bb4:                                              ; preds = %entry
  %14 = icmp eq %struct.clousure_type* %7, %9
  br i1 %14, label %bb5, label %bb6

bb5:                                              ; preds = %bb4
  ret void

bb6:                                              ; preds = %bb4, %bb2
  call void @_ZN13clousure_typeC2ERKS_(%struct.clousure_type* %5, %struct.clousure_type* %7)
  ret void
}

define private void @_ZN13clousure_typeC2ERKS_(%struct.clousure_type* %this, %struct.clousure_type* %rhs) {
  %1 = alloca %struct.clousure_type*, align 8
  %2 = alloca %struct.clousure_type*, align 8
  store %struct.clousure_type* %this, %struct.clousure_type** %1, align 8
  store %struct.clousure_type* %rhs, %struct.clousure_type** %2, align 8
  %3 = load %struct.clousure_type*, %struct.clousure_type** %1, align 8
  %4 = getelementptr %struct.clousure_type, %struct.clousure_type* %3, i32 0, i32 0
  store void ()* null, void ()** %4, align 8
  %5 = getelementptr %struct.clousure_type, %struct.clousure_type* %3, i32 0, i32 1
  store %struct.closure_vtable* null, %struct.closure_vtable** %5, align 8
  %6 = getelementptr %struct.clousure_type, %struct.clousure_type* %3, i32 0, i32 2
  store i8* null, i8** %6, align 8
  %7 = load %struct.clousure_type*, %struct.clousure_type** %2, align 8
  call void @_ZN13clousure_type4copyERKS_(%struct.clousure_type* %3, %struct.clousure_type* %7)
  ret void
}
```

To following passes are added, do I need to change any add any, which of these might be causing the problem?

```
    FPM->add(llvm::createCFGSimplificationPass());
    FPM->add(llvm::createInstructionCombiningPass());
    FPM->add(llvm::createPromoteMemoryToRegisterPass());
    FPM->add(llvm::createCFGSimplificationPass());
    FPM->add(llvm::createLICMPass());
    FPM->add(llvm::createLoopDeletionPass());
    FPM->add(llvm::createLoopUnrollPass());
    FPM->add(llvm::createSCCPPass());
    FPM->add(llvm::createCFGSimplificationPass());
    FPM->add(llvm::createInstructionCombiningPass());
    FPM->add(llvm::createDeadStoreEliminationPass());
    FPM->add(llvm::createAggressiveDCEPass());
    FPM->add(llvm::createCFGSimplificationPass());
    FPM->add(llvm::createTailCallEliminationPass());
```

Edit even if I remove all of the passes I still get the error!

At the moment it seems the problem stems from the following function `@"$static.159"` not that the function tries to `load @"$static.159$stub_ptr"`. The theory being that it cannot be removed as it is trying to load itself?

```
; Function Attrs: alwaysinline
define available_externally hidden void @"$static.159"(%struct.clousure_type*, %struct.clousure_type*) #0 {
entry:
  %2 = load void (%struct.clousure_type*, %struct.clousure_type*)*, void (%struct.clousure_type*, %struct.clousure_type*)** @"$static.159$stub_ptr"
  tail call void %2(%struct.clousure_type* %0, %struct.clousure_type* %1)
  ret void
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It took an upgrade to llvm 5.0 to finally get a handle on this error.

It was non of the theorised problems. Simply put in one of the functions I was storing in a function pointer, an alloca was not made due to a incorrectly initialized pointer in the c++ code that generated the above code leading to a `<badref>` found above. Note that the `<badref>` was only found by the optimizer later due to the use of function pointers!!

Why this pointer didn't cause a segfault earlier I don't know but it didn't, allowing the incorrect code generation. On llvm 5.0 the pointer gives a segfault as expected, allowing me to find the error.